# Dependency injection using guice in Dropwizard for set in constructor

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

Need help with the Dependency injection using guice in Dropwizard.

```
public class VendorHandlerFactory {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VendorHandlerFactory.class);

    private final Map<Vendor, VendorHandler> vendorHandlerMap;

    @Inject
    public VendorHandlerFactory(final Set<VendorHandler> vendorHandlers) {
        vendorHandlerMap = Maps.uniqueIndex(vendorHandlers, VendorHandler::getVendorType);
    }

    public VendorHandler getVendorHandler(final Vendor vendor) {
        VendorHandler vendorHandler = vendorHandlerMap.get(vendor);
        if (vendorHandler == null) {
           // do something
        }
        return vendorHandler;
    }
}
```

Vendor is enum and VendorHandler is an interface. I have VendorA implementing VendorHandler.

I am stuck with dependency injection. Getting below error :

```
2) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for Set<VendorHandler> was bound.

Requested by:
1  : VendorHandlerFactory.<init>
      \_ for 1st parameter
     at GuiceModule.configure(GuiceModule.java)
      \_ installed by: Elements$ElementsAsModule -> GuiceModule
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to register multiple `VendorHandler` implementations in different guice modules and inject all of them in `VendorHandlerFactory`. But guice is very strict and can't gather all registered implementations automatically (as spring). You need to manually describe each implementation as part of a set with [guice multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings):

```
Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), VendorHandler.class);
uriBinder.addBinding().to(VendorA.class)
```

Note that it is ok to call Multibinder.newSetBinder for each implementation registration (in each guide module where registration is required).

Only after that you can inject `Set<VenderHandler>` with all registered implementations.

Also, you can use a [MapBinder](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings#mapbinder) to bind handlers as map to be able to inject it as `Map<Vendor, VendorHandler>` without manual conversion